# Django 1.4: How to ignore fields, models in loaddata

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-fixtures

We have a compressed dumpdata of 15MB upload extracting goes to 100MB.
It has few models & fields that are not used in current tables.

Specifically, there are few `contenttypes` models which can be ignored, and one field `field_` that can be ignored in model.

Django 1.5 users `-ignorenonexistent` which safely does the job of ignoring. 
But how to do it efficiently in 1.4?

Answer (score -1):

In Django 1.4, you can't use the --ignorenonexistent option because it was introduced in Django 1.5. However, you can achieve a similar result by customizing the data loading process. Here's a general approach:

Filter out unnecessary models and fields: Before loading the data dump, filter out the unnecessary models and fields from the dump file. You can use tools like grep, awk, or sed to perform this filtering.

Load filtered data dump: Once you have the filtered dump file, load it into your database using the loaddata management command.

Here's an example of how you might filter out unnecessary models and fields using grep and sed:

```
# Filter out specific models from the dump
grep -v '"model": "app_name.model_name"' original_dump.json > filtered_dump.json

# Remove specific fields from the dump
sed -i 's/"field_name": .*,//g' filtered_dump.json

# Load the filtered data dump
python manage.py loaddata filtered_dump.json
```

Replace "app_name.model_name" with the name of the models you want to ignore and "field_name" with the names of the fields you want to ignore.

This approach allows you to customize the data loading process to exclude specific models and fields from your data dump, effectively achieving the same result as the --ignorenonexistent option in Django 1.5.